# Каким алгоритмом решить олимпиадную задачу про тома?

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

> На вход в файле INPUT.TXT подаётся две строчки: N - количество томов(максимум 32) и порядок томов книг (от 1 до N)
>   Нужно найти и вывести в файл OUTPUT.TXT **минимальное количество переставлений**, чтобы все тома были расположены **в порядке возрастания**,
>    при условии, что **можно брать любой том и ставить его только последним.**
>
> **Пример:**
>
> *Input.txt*   5   1 3 4 2 5
>
> *Output.txt*   3
>
> Так:
>   1.1 4 2 5 3
>   2.1 2 5 3 4
>   3.1 2 3 4 5

Каким алгоритмом можно решить это?

Comment: на каждом шаге надо находить минимальный том, стоящий не на своем месте, и ставить его в конец

Comment: @Igor, для пример на подходит. потому что минимальный не на своем месте будет 2, а начинают перестановку с трех

Comment: @Grundy - минимальный не на своем месте будет 4

Comment: @Igor, почему? в начале ж на своих местах только 1 и 5. кстати если начать с 4 - тоже будет не минимальное количество

Comment: а, пардон, минимальный не на своем месте будет 3. в начале на своих местах только 1, 2 и 5 - "на своем месте" - то есть в порядке возрастания

Comment: @Igor спасибо, принцип вроде бы понятен, попробую решить

Comment: @Igor всё смог сделать, спасибо огромное :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сравнивать расположение предыдущего и последующего томов (первого и второго, второго и третьего и т.д). И если естественный порядок нарушен, то переставить том с большим номером в конец.

В программе на PHP для этого использована функция `array_flip()`, переставляющая местами индексы массива и их значения.

Программа:

```
$order = array(1=>1,3,4,2,5);

function print_1d($ar, $title, $print_id){
    print "<br>$title";
    if($print_id) foreach($ar as $ind=>$item) print "$ind=>$item&emsp;";
    else foreach($ar as $item) print "$item&emsp;";
}

function order_transpose($k){
    global $n, $order;
    print "&emsp; k=$k";
    if($k != count($order)){
        $mind = $order[$k];
        for($i = $k; $i < $n; $i++) $order[$i]=$order[$i+1];
        $order[$n] = $mind; 
    }
}

$n = count($order);
print "N = $n"; 
$flip = array_flip($order);
print_1d($order, "<br>Order: ", false);
print_1d($flip, "Flip: ", true);
for($i = 1; $i < $n; $i++){
    if($flip[$i] > $flip[$i+1]){
        order_transpose($flip[$i+1]);
        $flip = array_flip($order);
        print_1d($order, "<br>Order: ", false);
        print_1d($flip, "Flip: ", true);
    } 
}
```

Результат:

```
N = 5

Order: 1 3 4 2 5 
Flip: 1=>1 3=>2 4=>3 2=>4 5=>5   k=2

Order: 1 4 2 5 3 
Flip: 1=>1 4=>2 2=>3 5=>4 3=>5   k=2

Order: 1 2 5 3 4 
Flip: 1=>1 2=>2 5=>3 3=>4 4=>5   k=3

Order: 1 2 3 4 5 
Flip: 1=>1 2=>2 3=>3 4=>4 5=>5
```